# Create dynamic hub context

Tags: c#, signalr

I have 2 projects.
C#
Both use Hubs/SignalR.
They both have the same methods so I created a shared abstract class in an external DLL.

So...

Project#1:

```
public class HubServerService : SharedHubService, IHostedService
{
    public HubServerService(IHubContext<ServerUserHub> hubContext)
    {
        HubContext = hubContext;
    }
}
```

Project#2:

```
public class HubServerService : SharedHubService, IHostedService
{
    public HubServerService(IHubContext<ClientUserHub> hubContext)
    {
        HubContext = hubContext;
    }
}
```

My Abstract class:

```
public abstract class SharedHubService
{
    protected IHubContext<dynamic> HubContext;
}
```

which obviously throws an error for 'dynamic'. I just put it in for illustration purposes (and removed all the methods for focus).

How can I 'overload' this?

Thanks

NB: Changing to the answer proposed by Lana I get this:

[image]

Comment: Probably `IHubContext<THub,T> Interface` in `SignalR` Can help you. Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubcontext-2?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @HasanFathi Thanks for your comment and link. I had looked at this before. But how would I use it in my abstract class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you should use template for your SharedHubService

```
public class HubServerService : SharedHubService<ServerUserHub>, IHostedService
{
    public HubServerService(IHubContext<ServerUserHub> hubContext)
    {
        HubContext = hubContext;
    }
}
```

abstract class looks like that

```
public abstract class SharedHubService<T> where T : Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub
{
    protected IHubContext<T> HubContext;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah I see your problem ...

Try the following code:

```csharp
    public abstract class SharedHubService<THub> where THub : Hub
    {
        protected IHubContext<THub> HubContext;
    }

    public class ClientUserHub : Hub
    {

    }

    public class HubServerService : SharedHubService<ClientUserHub>, IHostedService
    {
        public HubServerService(IHubContext<ClientUserHub> hubContext)
        {
            HubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but did not compile/build